# How to use W3WP.exe effectively to debug SharePoint applications?

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, w3wp.exe

Can anyone tell me how to effectively use w3wp.exe to debug sharepoint applications?

Comment: Please perform a little research before asking questions. Quick search gave this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are are running SharePoint on your development machine where you have Visual Studio installed - you can attach the debugger to the w3wp process, then breakpoints in your code will be hit when you 'touch' them from the web interface.

How to connect the debugger - good description in the MSDN article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx#Performing_Manual_Debugging

Comment: Thanks. For some weird reason I could not find this msdn article earlier. Thanks for the link. This looks good. Will try that.

Comment: @AndresMorales, you should also consider accepting answers of people if they work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your bespoke application that sits within sharepoint via Visual studio i would recommend that you download WSP builder it has dubugging options within it. I'm sure this does the same thing as the post above but it also has sharepoint related things within it that may be of use.

Comment: Does WSP builder works well with Sharepoint 2010? You dont really need WSP builder with SP 2010

Comment: You don't really need it but by default i installed it as i used to use it with 2007. I still use it to debug my applications in 2010 tho!